# I got new tires installed and now the left rear brake is stuck

Tags: brakes, tires, alignment, brake-calipers, brake-pad

2008 Honda CRV. Like I stated, I got new tires recently. I was trying to save a couple bucks, and went with a body shop that had a tire balancing machine. I think they messed up, because ever since I've been having problems.

Today I found out that my rear left brake pad is worn out and I can't get the caliper to disengage so I can remove it. I tried to remove the caliper to diagnose the problem, and it would not let go of the rotor. I am racking my brain for what could possibly be wrong. I'm at a complete loss.

The car was LITERALLY fine (I'm not BSing at all) before the shop got a hold of the car. I would like some advise before going back to have them fix the damage, because now .I am sure they don't know what they are doing.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shop did not wear away your brake pad.

While they, arguably, should have noticed the worn pads, you wanted a cheaper job and asked them to do the tires which they did. The fact that they have a tire balancing machine is not a sign of a bad job or shop.

To remove the caliper I would suggest using a pry bar to force the pads/pistons back some and then undoing the bolts and taking the caliper off. The rotors develop ridges and you have to get the pads over these.

Answer (score 0):

The probability that removing and reinstalling the wheels would mess up the caliper is relatively slim. But either or going to a body shop probably isnt best for brake work. If your attempting to solve the issue yourself and are capable of bleeding brake you might want to attempt releaving some pressure in the caliper by loosening the bleeder screw. if that doesnt free it up youll have to pry it off or try and open it manually while still on.